# How to compare doubles with 5 digits of precision?

Tags: c++, double, precision

I am trying to compare 2 **doubles** which fall in [0.0, 1.0].

My function (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17341 )-

```
inline bool isEqual(double x, double y)
{
    const double epsilon = 0.000001;
    return fabs(x - y) < epsilon;
}
```

Usage-

```
cerr << isEqual(1.000001, 1.000002) << endl;
cerr << isEqual(1.000010, 1.000020) << endl;
```

The output is-

```
0
0
```

Whereas I am expecting first to be `true`, second to be `false`. Please tell me where I am going wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: You will always get rouding errors with floating-point. And even if it were exact precision, `fabs(1.000001 - 1.000002)` would be _equal_ to `0.000001`, not strictly less than it.

Comment: The function has the wrong name. It does **not** test for equality, and should be called `nearly_equals` or something along that line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`1.000001` when limited to the usual 64-bit IEEE floating point representation is actually `1.0000009999999999177333620536956004798412`. Likewise `1.000002` is actually `1.0000020000000000575113290324225090444087`. The two are ever more slightly apart than `0.000001`.

You can use a very slightly larger comparison value to catch this:

```
    const double epsilon = 0.0000011;
```

It really isn't possible to completely eliminate any rounding problems with floating point numbers.

Comment: Thanks! That solved it. However I decided to solve problem with higher precision, and in end print answer with 5 digits of precision.

Comment: Anyway, doesn't `epsilon = 0.000001` give you **six** digits of precision instead of five?